# how do you make a .so library with autoconf, rather that a .la library?

Tags: shared, autoconf

I want to make a shared library with autoconf. However, I want the shared library to have a ".so" extension and not to begin with "lib". Basically, I want to make a plug-in that will get loaded with `dlopen`. Is there an easy way to do this?

When I try to create the .so file with autoconf, I get this error:

plugins/Makefile.am:3: `scan_bulk.la' is not a standard libtool library name
plugins/Makefile.am:3: did you mean`libscan_bulk.la'?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `-module` flag. It goes something like this:

```
pkglib_LTLIBRARIES = scan_bulk.la
scan_bulk_la_LDFLAGS = -module -avoid-version -shared
```

The module flag indicates to the Autotools that this is supposed to be a plugin.

Comment: Mailing list reference: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2004-05/msg00106.html

Comment: Also, it needs to be noted that the library with `.so` extension can be found in the `.libs` directory. When you do `make install` the `.so` library is installed together with the `.la` library.